# Question about creating this new data frame from previous one

Tags: r

I have a large data frame in R. And what I want is: If the end_station_name of the current ride equals to start_station_name of the next ride, then delete this current ride. For example, For the second ride, its  end_station_name equals to the start_station_name of the third ride, then, delete the second ride.

```
ride  start_station_name   end_station_name 
 1            A                   B
 2            B                   C
 3            C                   D
 4            M                   N
 5            K                   L
```

I want the result like this:

```
ride  start_station_name   end_station_name 
 3            C                   D
 4            M                   N
 5            K                   L
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward way is to use a `for` loop.

- *You need to modify the code if there are other forms of missing value (e.g., " ").
- ** You need to modify the code if you decide to delete rows/rides with missing values as well.

```
df <- data.frame(ride = 1:10,
                 start_station_name = c("A", "B", "C", "M", "K", "A", "B", "C", "M", "K"),
                 end_station_name = c("B", "C", "D", "N", NA,"B", "C", "D", "N", "L"))


n_row <- nrow(df)

for (i in 1:(n_row-1)){
  if(sum(is.na(df[i, ])) == 0){ # check whether there are missing values* (NA) in the row
    if(df$end_station_name[i] == df$start_station_name[i+1]){
      df[i, ] <- 0 # assign an arbitrary value for its row to be deleted later
    }
  }else{
    i <- i + 1 # skip** the row if there are missing values (NA)
  }
}

df1 <- df[which(df$ride != 0), ]


df1
```

**Result**

```
   ride start_station_name end_station_name
3     3                  C                D
4     4                  M                N
8     8                  C                D
9     9                  M                N
10   10                  K                L
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! But since I have a large data frame, when I use the code to run it, it has the error: "Error in if (df$end_station_name[i] == df$start_station_name[i +  :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" I am not sure how to fix this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Most probably there are missing values in your data frame. The revised answer takes this into account if the missing value is NA.